# Which IsolationLevel is best suitable in TransactionScope for processing my data successfully In C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, transactionscope

I have some data that I want to insert in 2 databases(1 MSSQL Server, 2 POSTGRY). If record is inserted in both database than both should be Committed otherwise both should be rollback.

Can anyone help me that which IsolationLevel I have to set in my C# code ?
Currently I am using following code.

for SQL database,

```
var sqlTransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable })
```

For PostGry database,

```
var npgsqlTransactionScope = npgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction()
```

But this code creates following issues sometimes:

```
- process still waiting for ShareLock on transaction
- canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid/reduce locking of database/table using isolationlevel snapshot. See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here for details. Database should be configure for this isolation level.